# How to understand the Expressjs documentation for function app.listen

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation

I'm reading expressjs API and encounter this function syntax:

```
app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])
```

Honestly, I interpreted above syntax as `app.listen(port, host, backlog, callback)` and because all 4 arguments are optional so it would be rewritten as `app.listen([port[, host[, backlog[, callback]]]])`

I don't know what I understand is correct or not, can you shed me some light on this matter ?

I found this documentation style is very ugly, difficult to read and sometimes misunderstanding.

Comment: Agreed on this being difficult to read. I think this means that, whether you pass 2, 3, or 4 arguments, Express will always treat the last argument as the `callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you think you can improve the documentation, you can suggest corrections and improvements as pull requests on the [ExpressJS.com github repo](https://github.com/expressjs/expressjs.com).

Second, all 4 variables are optional, with the exception that you can only provide `backlog` if you've provided a `host` (see that the 2 are surrounded by an extra pair of `[]`?). Similarly, you can only provide `host` and `backlog` if you've provided a `port`.
This is just a very functional way of showing the dependencies between parameters.

Comment: So extra pair of [] denotes for dependency between parameters, right ?

Comment: Yes. Consider this sequence: `[a, [b, [c]]`. It means the following inputs would be considered valid: no parameters, `a`, `a, b`, `a, b, c`. As you can see `a, c` would be invalid, since `c` is dependent on `b`.